# gfortran error : Unexpected element '<' in format string

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I suffer the pain to compile the old fortran source code using gfortran.
I did not have many experience to do this, so please help me to correct the source code based on the error message.

disturbance.f:1416.31:

```
 1505     format ( I7, E12.3, < npftu>E10.3 )          
Error: Unexpected element '<' in format string at (1)
```

please note that there is no space between npftu and < >.

Answer (score 4):

Variable `FORMAT` expressions are non-standard and are **not** supported by gfortran ([link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Variable-FORMAT-expressions.html) to the documentation).

I know your pain - I've also struggled with this problem many times before until I migrated completely to another compilers collection...

Comment: Thanks. The easier way for me is just to know the columns for npftu. In my case, I use 10 here, so the new code would like: 1505 format ( I7, E12.3, 10E10.3 )

Comment: Knowing the columns of what you need is just a particular case. Being able to use a variable string format is much more flexible, even if you fix that variable to 10 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. The easier way for me is just to know the columns for npftu. In my case, I use 10 here, so the new code would like: 1505 format ( I7, E12.3, 10E10.3 )